# Search by the order of tokens

Tags: solr

Folks,

We have one requirement where we want to search the items in solr by order of tokens.

e.g. If q=google facebook

Then it should give the matching documents with keyword "google" first
then it should give matching documents with keyword "facebook"

Given below is the config but it is not working.

```
   <fieldType name="string_ci" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"> 
    <analyzer type="index">         
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="30"/>
    </analyzer>  
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/> 
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: how many query terms are we talking about?

Comment: We will have 5-6 query terms

Answer (score 0):

Each term can be given a boost starting with the first and then delta decrementing each next term. For an example, it could be something like "google^0.9 facebook^0.5" This would boost google over facebook.The boost is multiplied into the normal score for the clause and will affect its importance relative to other clauses.

Comment: Ok here is another problem what if we want to search with the term "google facebook" followed by "google" and "facebook. Can we give a term like "(google^2.0 facebook^1.0)^10"

Comment: Well you can do nested boosts, possible. https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#Boosting%20a%20Term

Comment: is this syntax correct fielddemo:(google^2.0 facebook^1.0)^10.0 OR fieldonedemo:(yahoo^2.0 twitter^1.0)^5.0 . Not getting clear documentation on this syntax.